# Ajax Post with [ ] in parameter name

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I need to send an AJAX post to a PHP script which expect [] in the Parameter name.

my code:

```
$("#form").submit(function () {
   var salutation = $("input[name='salutation ']:checked").val();
   var name = $("#name").val();
   var surename= $("#surename").val();
   var origin = "true";

   var post = jQuery.post(url, {
        salutation: salutation,
        name: name,
        surname: surname,
        origin[Newsletterform]: origin
    });

    post.done(function(data) {
        console.log("webservice-done")
    });
});
```

The problem is in the line with `origin[Newsletterform]: origin`.

It tells me that there is an error in this line.

If I remove the `[DATA]` part and only use `origin: origin` it tells me that there is no Error in my Code. But I need to send the Parameter with the [DATA] part.

I can't change something in the PHP script because it is not mine and there is no possibility to change something on that side.

Is there any way to send the parameter name with [DATA]?

It should be like `SCRIPT_URL?salutation=salutation&name=name&lastname=lastname&origin[Newsletterform]=true`.

Comment: why do you need the [data] part?

Comment: because the script exepcts the origin, which i cant set myself, to be directly on the parameter side inside the square brackets. I can set the DATA inside myself. so when i send from [Newsletterform] i can later filter the the entrys by origin

Comment: Quotes: `"origin[Newsletterform]": origin`

Comment: Thanks @Juhana this totaly solved it. wow. I'm a bit shoked that it realy only took the ' '. I was alreay tried to write some kind of replace script. Thank for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a property to an object with that syntax you can wrap it in quotes:

```
var postData = {
    salutation: salutation,
    name: name,
    surname: surname,
    'origin[Newsletterform]': origin
}

var post = $.post(url, postData);
```

Or use bracket notation:

```
var postData = {
    salutation: salutation,
    name: name,
    surname: surname
}
postData['origin[Newsletterform]'] = origin;

var post = $.post(url, postData);
```

Comment: Thank for the Answer. The postData['origin[Newsletterform]'] = origin; fixed my problem. It seems like i was only missing the ' ' Part. Thank you for the help

Comment: This works, but it's unnecessarily complex (you could just quote the key in the original literal.)